# Using IIS ARR to route SOAP requests

Tags: c#, iis, soap, url-routing, reverse-proxy

The situation is that we have some SOAP (asmx) services that are version dependent upon a 3rd party software.  These services reside on domainA.

We are in the process of migrating to a new version of the 3rd party software where the existing SOAP services will not be able to reside because of a version incompatibility. Currently the upgraded stuff lives on temp.domainA.

We are developing new services to replace the old SOAP services and will plug in wcf routing or something to save us from the next 3rd party version upgrade party.

Ideally, once temp.domainA is all ready to go we will switch that dns to be domainA and change the old domainA to be old.domainA there for breaking all existing applications referencing the soap services.

I've been fooling around with IIS and ARR matching on a common naming convention that the soap services have and trying to have those requests routed. This works very well for Get requests but not so well for POST requests which is what soap uses.

I set up a little test by having 2 identical services running, one on a test server and one on my local machine.  The one on my local machine returns different data than the one on the test server so I can tell which one is being invoked.

I set up ARR's proxy in my local iis to be a reverse proxy to the service on the test server. I set up a url rewrite rule to inspect the incoming requests based on the naming convention of the soap service url.

If I browse to the soap endpoint via a browser and httpget's everything works as planned. I get a response from the remote test server with the request originating from localhost.

When I run the test app which makes the same call except as a post with soap I get this error

`exception.message: There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost/webservice/Default.asmx that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
exception.InnerException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.`

my settings

[image]

and then for Proxy Type i have

- use url rewrite to inspect checked
- enable ssl offloading checked
- and reverse proxy: set to remote.test.server