# Is it possible to programmatically set fields of ARR (IIS)?

Tags: c#, iis, arr

I want to set a reverse proxy through ARR. Is it possible to do it programmaticaly using C#?

Comment: [Using IIS ARR to route SOAP requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027583/using-iis-arr-to-route-soap-requests) and [IIS7 Application Request Routing HTTPS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529754/iis7-application-request-routing-https) might put some light on what you are trying to do

Comment: In the actual installation I have to set the 'enable proxy' option of ARR. So I have to set this option programmatically through C#.

Comment: how to set reverse proxy of IIS programmatically using c#?

Comment: Yes, It is possible as I enabled ARR depend on my situation, but it is a little complicated.